# UPDATE com vários registros de outra tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela `T1` onde eu tenho o `ID`.

Tenho uma tabela `T2` onde pega o `ID_T1`(*Foreign Key*) da `T1`. 

Tenho uma tabela `T3` onde pega o `ID_T1`(*Foreign Key*) da `T1` e o `ID_T2`(*Foreign Key*) da `T2`.

Na tabela `T3`, os ID's da `T1` estão certinhos, porém, a `T3` eu criei depois que esses registros foram inseridos, ou seja, estão com os registros da coluna `ID_T2` a `NULL`. Tem alguma maneira onde eu consiga fazer algum `UPDATE` na `T3`, passando todos os ID's da `T2` da maneira correta?

Segue abaixo o código que estou tentando:

```
UPDATE  T3 
SET     T3.ID_T2 =  (
                        SELECT      T2.ID 
                        FROM        T2 
                        INNER JOIN  T3 ON T2.ID_T1 = T3.ID_T1
                    ) 
WHERE   T3.ID_T1 =  (
                        SELECT      T1.ID 
                        FROM        T1 
                        INNER JOIN  T3 ON T3.ID_T1 = T1.ID 
                        INNER JOIN  T2 ON T2.ID_T1 = T3.ID_T1
                    )
```

Em SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Se o objetivo é apenas atualizar o _ID_T2_ da tabela _T3_, basta retirar o _WHERE_, penso que assim resulta.

Comment: @JoãoMartins Então cara, tirando o WHERE, ele altera todos os campos para o mesmo ID, não é isso que eu estou querendo.

Comment: Certo, tem toda a razão. Nova resposta com código abaixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta *query* poderá resolver o seu problema:

```
UPDATE      T3 
SET         T3.ID_T2 = T2.ID
FROM        T3
INNER JOIN  T1 ON T1.ID     = T3.ID_T1
INNER JOIN  T2 ON T2.ID_T1  = T1.ID
```

O que faz basicamente é atualizar o `ID_T2` com o `ID` que vem da tabela `T2`, que por seu lado está associada à tabela `T1` pelo `ID_T1`.

Comment: Dessa maneira, agora ele só muda um registro. Só está mudando o ultimo registro da tabela T2.

Comment: Então isso pode estar relacionado com a informação que as 3 tabelas têm.
O que lhe é devolvido quando executa a _query_ mas com _SELECT_ ao invés do _UPDATE_?

Comment: Então, ele me traz uma linha, referente aos dados do último registro que foi inserido.

Comment: Certo, então na tabela _T3_ apenas existe um registo que tenha ligação entre a tabela _T1_ e a _T2_, já que estamos a ligá-las por _INNER JOIN_.

Comment: Realmente, agora funcionou. Só tinha 1 registro mesmo relacionado!

Comment: Perfeito ;)! Se puder marcar a resposta como correta, agradecia!